# Angular 7 Deployment in NodeJS: Base href attribute added to header of index.html works correctly for home page but no routes

Tags: node.js, angular, express, deployment

**Stack -** Angular7, NodeJS with Express. My Angular app should only work on a portion of my site and route only under domain.com/finance, the rest is all plain HTML, CSS, and JS.

**Expected behavior -** My app and all its pages should route on a base href that I set in the header of index.html and in the build options but it only works on the app's landing page.

**Actual behavior-** My app routes correctly to its homepage but routing to a different page seems to ignore the base href attribute. For example, I would expect the app to route to domain.com/finance/budget page but instead it routes to domain.com/budget when I leave my landing page. Manually navigating to /finance/budget redirects to the landing page.

**Troubleshooting done so far -** Triple checked that my base href tag is set in the compiled index.html, tried the --base-href /finance/ option on and off, tried the --deploy-url /finance/ option on and off, served the finance-app folder statically off and on (only serves the homepage when it's on), watched videos where others go through the exact same steps that I have and had success where I have not.

**Other symptoms -** In the troubleshooting videos I watched, I noticed that the --base-href /finance/ option should have created a /finance folder under my compiled project directory, but it did not. If I leave my project as it is compiles, the whole thing fails because it can't load the JS files. If I manually move the JS files to a /finance subdirectory then I can get to my homepage but it won't route correctly.

**Most likely problems -** My server is misconfigured to handle having an Angular app at that route.

**The code:**

1. **My server:** (relevant routes and options)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/projects/finance-app'));

app.get('/finance*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/projects/finance-app/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/projects/finance-app/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server listening on port ' + PORT));
```

2. **My app index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Finance App</title>
    <base href="/finance/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

3. **Build command with options**

`ng build --prod --base-href /finance/`

4. **Site's folder structure:** (relevant parts)

```
portfolio/
├── node_modules/
│   └── ......
├── projects/
│   ├── finance-app/
|   |   ├── finance/
|   |   |  └── (angular javascript and css files)
|   |   └── index.html
├── public/
|   ├── (other project public assets folders)
|   ├── views/
|   |   └── home.html
|   ├── scripts/
|   └── styles/
├── app.js
├── package.json
└── package-lock.json
```

4. **Angular project routes** (relevant parts)

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'beginner-guide', component: GuideComponent},
  {path: 'retirement', component: RetirementCalcComponent},
  {path: 'loan', component: LoanComponent},
  {path: 'budget', component: BudgetCalcComponent},
  {path: 'budget/results', component: BudgetResultsComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RetirementCalcComponent,
    GuideComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    BudgetCalcComponent,
    BudgetResultsComponent,
    LoanComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    ),
  ],
  providers: [
   {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
```

Comment: When you say you expect `domain.com/finance/budget`, that means you have to have a budget component folder inside finance component folder. I do not see budget component in your finance component folder.

Comment: So you say that the build command does not generate any `finance` folder inside `dist` folder, I am correct?. Why your server is mapping `finance` to `finance-app`?, you should not need to do any mapping like that, `finance` should go to `finance`.